# mkdir's "-p" option

Tags: unix, command-line, command-line-arguments, directory-structure

So this doesn't seem like a terribly complicated question I have, but it's one I can't find the answer to.  I'm confused about what the `-p` option does in Unix.  I used it for a lab assignment while creating a subdirectory and then another subdirectory within that one.  It looked like this:

```
mkdir -p cmps012m/lab1
```

This is in a private directory with normal rights (`rlidwka`). Oh, and would someone mind giving a little explanation of what `rlidwka` means?  I'm not a total noob to Unix, but I'm not really familiar with what this means.  Hopefully that's not too vague of a question.

Comment: `man mkdir` will answer your question. As for "rlidwka", I have no idea; you'll need to give us some more context.

Comment: The `man mkdir`page found on macOS has a more intuitive description of the `-p` option (see [here](https://ss64.com/osx/mkdir.html)). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015076/814702) is useful.

Answer (score 232):

The man pages is the best source of information you can find... and is at your fingertips: `man mkdir` yields this about `-p` switch:

```
-p, --parents
    no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Use case example: Assume I want to create directories `hello/goodbye` but none exist:

```
$mkdir hello/goodbye
mkdir:cannot create directory 'hello/goodbye': No such file or directory
$mkdir -p hello/goodbye
$
```

`-p` created both, `hello` and `goodbye`

This means that **the command will create all the directories necessaries to fulfill your request, not returning any error in case that directory exists**.

About `rlidwka`, Google has a very good memory for acronyms :). My search returned this for example: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~help/afs/afs_acls.html

```
 Directory permissions

l (lookup)
    Allows one to list the contents of a directory. It does not allow the reading of files. 
i (insert)
    Allows one to create new files in a directory or copy new files to a directory. 
d (delete)
    Allows one to remove files and sub-directories from a directory. 
a (administer)
    Allows one to change a directory's ACL. The owner of a directory can always change the ACL of a directory that s/he owns, along with the ACLs of any subdirectories in that directory. 

File permissions

r (read)
    Allows one to read the contents of file in the directory. 
w (write)
    Allows one to modify the contents of files in a directory and use chmod on them. 
k (lock)
    Allows programs to lock files in a directory.
```

Hence `rlidwka` means: *All permissions on*.

It's worth mentioning, as @KeithThompson pointed out in the comments, that not all Unix systems support ACL. So probably the `rlidwka` concept doesn't apply here.

Comment: But not all Unix-like systems support ACLs, so `rlidwka` may or may not be meaningful.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well I agree, I just wanted mention what the acronym stands for.

Comment: Yes, but often just answering someone's question is less helpful than providing background information needed to understand the answer.

Comment: I'll point it out in the answer. I just wasn't aware of this. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: This answer is the most verbose way possible of saying "RTFM, let me google that for you" and I love it. I once was a noobie intern that didn't know anything, and forgot that before asking my manager I should just google it. Go easy on these new guys; sometimes it's hard to figure out what to google. You don't know what you don't know. But everyone gets more skillful at googling after years of doing it.

Comment: @Dagrooms btw I came here cause I don't clearly understand the one sentence description written in the manual !

Comment: No info on https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir

Answer (score 10):

**mkdir [-switch] foldername**

`-p` is a switch, which is optional. It will create a subfolder and a parent folder as well, even if parent folder doesn't exist.

From the man page:

```
-p, --parents no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Example:

```
mkdir -p storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache}
```

This will create subfolder sessions,views,cache inside framework folder irrespective of whether 'framework' was available earlier or not.

Answer (score 6):

`-p|--parent` will be used if you are trying to create a directory with `top-down` approach. That will create the parent directory then child and so on iff none exists.

> -p, --parents
>       no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

About `rlidwka` it means giving full or administrative access. Found it here https://itservices.stanford.edu/service/afs/intro/permissions/unix.

Answer (score 4):

PATH: Answered long ago, however, it maybe more helpful to think of -p as "Path" (easier to remember), as in this causes mkdir to create every part of the path that isn't already there.

mkdir -p /usr/bin/comm/diff/er/fence

if /usr/bin/comm already exists, it acts like:
mkdir /usr/bin/comm/diff
mkdir /usr/bin/comm/diff/er
mkdir /usr/bin/comm/diff/er/fence

As you can see, it saves you a bit of typing, and thinking, since you don't have to figure out what's already there and what isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `-p` is an argument to the `mkdir` command specifically, not the whole of Unix. Every command can have whatever arguments it needs.

In this case it means "parents", meaning `mkdir` will create a directory and any parents that don't already exist.